# Наложение музыки в середине другой музыки

Tags: php

Вообщем такая задача. Есть например какая-то мелодия  и мне нужно в середине неё вставить другую мелодию. Реально ли это на PHP? Если да, то напишите, пожалуйста алгоритм или функции для работы...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покопайтесь в [классах для работы со звуком](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/class/34.html).